# Как тип string преобразовать в nonetype?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qcombobox, qspinbox

Нужно решить следующую задачу. В *Qt Designer* сделал интерфейс, в котором есть `spinBox` и двенадцать `comboBox`. 
В зависимости от значения в `spinBox` часть `comboBox` должна деактивироваться и быть недоступна для работы.

Для этого при изменении значения в `spinBox` сигнал вызывает функцию, в которой есть цикл, чтобы связать значение, считанное из `spinBox`, с нужными именами `comboBox`.

Имена `comboBox` выглядят как **`comboBox_1`** и т.д.

При запуске кода появляется ошибка:

> "AttributeError: 'Ui_Calc_prop_mod' object has no attribute 'comboBoxName'".

Если напрямую прописать например:

```
self.comboBox_3.setEnabled(False)
```

то третий comboBox деактивируется.

Насколько я разобрался, проблема в том, что тип `self.comboBoxName.setEnabled(False)` должен быть **`Nonetype`**, а у меня тип `comboBoxName` **`string`**. Т.е. надо или `comboBoxName` сделать **`Nonetype`** или `self.comboBoxName.setEnabled(False)` сделать **`Nonetype`**.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? Или каким другим образом можно решить эту проблему?

```
from Ui_Calc_prop import*
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Calc_prop_mod(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Calc_prop):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.spinBox.setValue(1)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.chng)

    def chng(self):
        constituent_count = int(self.spinBox.cleanText())
        for k in range(constituent_count + 1, 13):
            comboBoxName = 'comboBox_' + str(k)
            self.comboBoxName.setEnabled(False)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не предоставили минимально-воспроизводимый пример, это не хорошо.

Учитывая что это ваш ПЕРВЫЙ вопрос, я покажу вам один из возможных вариантов.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# ??? from Ui_Calc_prop import *


class Ui_Calc_prop_mod(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):                    # , Ui_Calc_prop):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)

        self.num = 13

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setRange(1, self.num - 1)
        self.spinBox.setValue(1)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.chng)
        
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        vbox.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        
        for i in range(1, self.num):
            comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            comboBox.setObjectName(f'comboBox_{i}')
            vbox.addWidget(comboBox)

        self.chng(1)

    def chng(self, value):
        for k in range(1, self.num):
            if value >= k:
                self.findChild(QtWidgets.QComboBox, f'comboBox_{k}').setEnabled(True)
            else:
                self.findChild(QtWidgets.QComboBox, f'comboBox_{k}').setEnabled(False)            


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Ui_Calc_prop_mod()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Это действительно то, что я пытался сделать. Замечание про воспроизводимый пример учту. В целом с вашим кодом разобрался, но не понял зачем в методе __init__ вызывается функция self.chng(1), если она вызывается с помощью сигнала при изменении значения в spinBox. Причем, если эту строку закомментировать, то все работает так же. Прошу прощения, если что-то напутал в терминологии.

Comment: Про self.chng(1) разобрался. Это чтобы при запуске программы до сигнала был активирован первый comboBox.

Comment: @OstapukYA да, это так.

Answer (score 0):

```
from Ui_Calc_prop import*
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Calc_prop_mod(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Calc_prop):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.spinBox.setValue(1)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.chng)

    def chng(self):
        constituent_count = int(self.spinBox.cleanText())
        for k in range(constituent_count + 1, 13):
            comboBoxName = 'comboBox_' + str(k)
            comboboxfind = self.findChild(QtGui.QComboBox, comboBoxName)
            comboboxfind.setEnabled(False)
```

Comment: твои combobox должны быть наследниками Ui_Calc_prop_mod. Код ищет всех комбобокс наследников и ищет конкретным названием в строке. и потом выключает. Надеюсь понятно условие. но если потом еще раз изменить то они заново не появятся. Напиши это сам. обратно включи в начале функции все комбобокс.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ваше решение помогло. Только в строке comboboxfind = self.findChild(QtGui.QComboBox, comboBoxName) пришлось заменить QtGui.QComboBox на QtWidgets.QComboBox, потому что возникала ошибка, что QtGui не имеет атрибута QComboBox. Но это моя вина, что не предоставил воспроизводимый пример.